# Laravel AuthController кастомизация

Tags: laravel, auth, role

Сейчас я использую стандартный Auth, из коробки. Моя задача сделать так чтобы залогининый юзер с правами админа мог регистрировать пользователей самостоятельно, в тот же момент только этот пользователь может регистрировать пользователей.
Раут

```
/register
```

после авторизации недоступен, где он защищен непонятно.
По сути надо сделать его доступным и доступным только для моего типа пользователей, в симфони проверка на тип пользователя делается через voter, а ларавеле пока не знаю, но делать глупое

```
if($usertype == 1)
```

нет желания. Как кастомизировать регистрацию и эти рауты?

Comment: А какую версию фреймворка используете?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.6.27

Comment: В этой версии нет authcontroller , там в коробке идет logincontroller и registercontroller отдельно

Answer (score 1):

Защитите роут ('register') новым посредником middleware('auth_admin'), настройте этот посредник, добавив в него проверку прав пользователя, например через поле role в таблице users. Не забудьте зарегистрировать новый посредник в ядре kernel.php. Тогда только определенный тип пользователя сможет регистрировать других пользователей